# Condicional dentro de una consulta linq

Tags: c#, linq

quiero seleccionar de una lista de una clase producto todos los elementos que contengan en la propiedad nombre lo que le pase por un string o que los contenga en la propiedad AliasNombre asi que la consulta me quedaria algo asi

```
(from x in _ListaProductos
 where x.Nombre.Contains(ConsultaProducto) || x.CadenaAlias.Contains(ConsultaProducto)
 select x).ToList<Producto>();
```

lo que pasa es que no siempre en la propiedad CadenaAlias habra valor, entonces si CadenaAlias es null me salta una excepcion.

mi pregunta es, ¿si hay una forma de condicionar esa parte de la consulta, para que solo ejecute esa parte de la consuta solo cuando CadenaAlias sea diferente de null?

Comment: Saludos. Para aquello que pueda ser null; te sugiero `(x.CadenaAlias??"").Contains(ConsultaProducto)` (esto para el caso de `string`).

Comment: hola, ahora ya no me salta la excepcion pero no me devuelve elementos. me podrias decir como se llama esa expresion para googlearlo? y muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Podes hacer un solo metodo y solo pasar el condicional necesario a ese where y no tener dos metodos iguales. Te dejo la solucion, como respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el ejemplo con una clase Persona, ya que no se como se llaman tus clases pero seria facil de adaptar.

Creo el repositorio de los datos y le cargo info.

```
        public static List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();

        personas.Add(new Persona { Nombre = "Ramiro" });
        personas.Add(new Persona { Nombre = "Jazmin" });
        personas.Add(new Persona { Nombre = "Bruno" });
```

Llamo la funcion y le paso la condicion que quiero y esta me devuelve mi objeto.
En un caso podes filtrar por nombre, en otro por apellido y no tenes que manejar un condicional dentro del where, te queda mas limpio y reutilizable.

```
        Persona p1 = Buscar(x => x.Nombre == "Ramiro");
```

En los parametros del metodo le paso un Func con el tipo de objeto y bool como respuesta.

```
     private static Persona Buscar(Func<Persona, bool> condicional)
     {
        return personas.Where(condicional).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
     }
```

Si no te queda claro. Coloca tus clases y lo hacemos con tus propiades y nombre de clase.

Comment: Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution) para entender por qué no puedes poner `FirstOrDefault` en esa *query*.

Comment: A mi me funciona correctamente, donde dices que esta el error?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo pude resolver, soy un conciente que el codigo quedo un poco engorroso pero hace su trabajo como quiero. Asi quedo:

```
(from x in _ListaProductos
where x.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(ConsultaProducto.ToLowerInvariant()) || (x.CadenaAlias != null && x.CadenaAlias.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(ConsultaProducto.ToLowerInvariant())))
select x).ToList<Producto>();
```

_ListaProductos es una Lista de la clase producto.

La Clase producto tiene muchas propiedades pero las que se utilizan en la consulta es Nombre(String) y CadenaAlias(String).

Y ConsultaProducto es un string que utilizo para recibir por que palabra se va a filtrar.